# RFC 8767 and delegation

Tags: domain-name-system

I do not get the following sentence from the [RFC 8767](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8767#section-4):

> When no authorities are able to be reached during a resolution
> attempt, the resolver should attempt to refresh the delegation and
> restart the iterative lookup process with the remaining time on the
> query resolution timer.  This resumption should be done only once per
> resolution effort.

Specifically:

> the resolver should attempt to refresh the delegation

What do we call delegation here? I do not understand why it is talking about delegation when it comes to recursive resolver.

Answer (score 2):

What is referred to as the *delegation* here would be the `NS` recordset (and glue as appropriate) served by the parent zone nameservers.

Eg for `example.com`, it would be the `NS` recordset for `example.com` that is served by the `com` zone nameservers when sending referral responses.

Comment: ok makes totally sense, thank you